# Testing http intercetpor in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, http-get

I'm testing an angular2 HTTP interceptor and I get the following error:

```
Error: Expected no open requests, found 1: GET /web-service

it('check if request path...',
     inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController], (http: HttpClient, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
        http.get('/web-service').subscribe(
            response => {
                expect(response).toBeTruthy();
            }
        );
    }));
```

I don't seem to understand the error. An open request is found and the response is there so my expect statement should pass, instead it throws an error that it doesn't expect an request?